# Type testing in Google spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

Is it possible to test for integers or strings in a Google Spreadsheet and respond to each differently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To test for string you can use `=ISTEXT(A1)`

To test for an Integer you will need to do something like this:

`=IF( (D8 = int(D8)), TRUE, FALSE)`

Which basically converts the value to an Integer and then checks if it is the same as the original pre-converted value.

Comment: I think `=D8=int(D8)` will do. (not tested)

Comment: @Wilson - Yes you are correct :)

Comment: A blank cell will return a false positive for an integer with the current approach, and a text string will return an error.  Your approach can be tweaked `=AND(IFERROR(INT(D8)=D8,0), LEN(D8))` to address both cases.